# Keep field up-to-date in multiple thread modify&access in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading

The method Stop can't modifies field isRunning in another thread, why?

Here is a sample from MSDN, but the field is modified by only one thread.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.110).aspx

Following is my code.

```
public class Worker
{
    private volatile bool isRunning;

    public void Run()
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    private void DoSomething(object state)
    {
        this.isRunning = true;
        while (this.isRunning)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("working...");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("stopped.");
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting in your code?

Comment: I want to modify field in multiple thread and keep the value up-to-date.

Comment: But I tested your code and it does exactly what you want. Maybe you could add some inline comments to point out what is not working as you expect.

Comment: @ZoranCausev points where the mistake is.

Comment: I agree, but you didn't include the real problem (the class usage) in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually works. If you run this code, you will see that it works just fine:

```
Worker worker = new Worker();
worker.Run();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
worker.Stop();
```

The problem is that when you schedule a thread for execution, it needs some time to execute. In a case when you skip the Thread.Sleep(1000) in my example, you immediately set the isRunning field to false, which is then set to true when the thread executes. That's why it never finishes.

Comment: Your suggestion will work, but I cannot agree with it. The "client" which uses the Worker should be not allowed to know anything of the internals of that class. So the programmer who uses Worker should not have knowledge of where "isRunning" is set. This having said, the developer should be able to call Run and Stop immediately without your pause, because that should simply work. The delay is simply a trick to prevent the "hidden" racing condition inside the Worker-class.

Comment: I never said it was a good solution. I just pointed out the reason why the call to Stop didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this.isRunning to only isRunning  This refers to the current thread in the memory while the field is running in another thread.

Comment: Incorrect. "this" referes to an instance of an object. This instance can be shared by multiple threads. As a result, this.isRunning can be shared (and modified) by multiple threads. Second, in this case adding or removing "this" does not change anything because code still referes to the same field in the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Move your line `isRunning = true` to the function `Run()`, like this:

public class Worker
{
    private volatile bool isRunning;

```
public void Run()
{
    this.isRunning = true;
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoSomething);
}

public void Stop()
{
    this.isRunning = false;
}

private void DoSomething(object state)
{
    while (this.isRunning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("working...");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("stopped.");
}
```

}

This change will ensure that `isRunning` is true, when the function `DoSomething` is called. If `Stop` has been called between `Run` and `DoSomething`, the thread will actually stop immediately.

Comment: I want to modify&access field in multiple thread, not just modify it in one thread.

Comment: Than I do not understand your question. In how many threads do you want to call "Run", in how many threads do you want to call "Stop" and in how many threads do you run "DoSomething"? I ask this, because a thread does not modify your field "isRunning", only your methods do. And a thread will call your methods.